# Cannot upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 - "Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu..."

Tags: ppa, do-release-upgrade

Running `sudo do-release-upgrade` stumbles upon an error:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

I'm attaching apt.log and main.log
https://gist.github.com/omerbn/6e44593d8cab464be7f959b426d1c31c

What should I do next?

Thanks,

O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install ppa-purge

   ```
   sudo apt install ppa-purge
   ```
2. In `main.log` locate the faulty packages:

   ```
   grep disabled /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log
   ```

   Output example:

   ```
   2021-03-19 02:44:31,173 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal main # disabled on upg...
   ```
3. Remove ppa

   ```
   sudo ppa-purge kisak/kisak-mesa
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it simply doing this:

- 1.- Disable ppa repositories from Software and Updates > Other Software
- 2.- Clean apt:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```

- 3.- Proceed to upgrade

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: It did not work for me :\

Answer (score 2):

I followed the current accepted answer of @Omeriko:
Install ppa-purge

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
```

In main.log locate the faulty packages:

```
grep disabled /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log
```

Output example:

```
2021-03-19 02:44:31,173 DEBUG entry '# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal main # disabled on upg...
```

Remove ppa

```
sudo ppa-purge kisak/kisak-mesa
```

then also @Ecofintech's answer of:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```

and finally upgrade:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

thank you to both for answers that contributed to my system being upgraded